# Faster way for Changing the Array Structure in Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

I am wondering whether there is a faster way to do what I am trying to do below - basically, unnesting an array and creating a groupArray with different columsn.

```
-- create table

CREATE TABLE default.t15 ( product String,  indx Array(UInt8),  col1 String,  col2 Array(UInt8)) ENGINE = Memory ;

--insert values

INSERT into t15 values ('p',[1,2,3],'a',[10,20,30]),('p',[1,2,3],'b',[40,50,60]),('p',[1,2,3],'c',[70,80,90]);

-- select values
    SELECT * from t15;
```

```html
┌─product─┬─indx────┬─col1─┬─col2───────┐
│ p       │ [1,2,3] │ a    │ [10,20,30] │
│ p       │ [1,2,3] │ b    │ [40,50,60] │
│ p       │ [1,2,3] │ c    │ [70,80,90] │
└─────────┴─────────┴──────┴────────────┘
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```html
┌─product─┬─indx_list─┬─col1_arr──────┬─col2_arr───┐
│ p       │         1 │ ['a','b','c'] │ [10,40,70] │
│ p       │         2 │ ['a','b','c'] │ [20,50,80] │
│ p       │         3 │ ['a','b','c'] │ [30,60,90] │
└─────────┴───────────┴───────────────┴────────────┘
```

How I am doing it -> [little slow for what I need this for]

```html
SELECT   product, 
         indx_list, 
         groupArray(col1)      col1_arr, 
         groupArray(col2_list) col2_arr 
FROM     ( 
                  SELECT   product, 
                           indx_list, 
                           col1, 
                           col2_list 
                  FROM     t15 
                  ARRAY JOIN
                           indx AS indx_list, 
                           col2 AS col2_list 
                  ORDER BY indx_list, 
                           col1
          )x 
GROUP BY product, 
         indx_list;
```

Basically, I am unnesting the array and then grouping them back.
Is there a better and faster way to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it faster it look like you can avoid subselect and the global ORDER BY in  it. So something like:

```
SELECT 
    product, 
    indx_list, 
    groupArray(col1) AS col1_arr, 
    groupArray(col2_list) AS col2_arr
FROM t15 
ARRAY JOIN 
    indx AS indx_list, 
    col2 AS col2_list
GROUP BY 
    product, 
    indx_list
```

If you need the arrays to be sorted it's usually better to sort it inside each group separately, using **arraySort**.

Answer (score 0):

I would make the query a little simple to reduce the count of array joins to one, that probably improves performance:

```sql
SELECT
    product,
    index as indx_list,
    groupArray(col1) as col1_arr,
    groupArray(element) as col2_arr
FROM
(
    SELECT
        product,
        arrayJoin(indx) AS index,
        col1,
        col2[index] AS element
    FROM default.t15
)
GROUP BY
    product,
    index;
```

Maybe make sense to change the table structure to get rid of any arrays. I would suggest the flat  schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE default.t15 ( 
  product String,  
  valueId UInt8,  /* indx */
  col1 String, /* col1 */
  value UInt8) /* col2 */
  ENGINE = Memory ;
```